# Pivot DataGridView

Tags: mysql, winforms, c#-4.0

So, imagine a spreadsheet, where the upper cells represent days of the month and the lines represent the results of some calculations, again for the day.

I would apply this to a dataGridView.
Each column is represented by a day of the month, should contain several lines with the results of some calculations on that day that recovery through queries to databases.

In practice, when I run the fill of the GridView, I see populate, in sequence, and vertically, the cells on the day.

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking, at this point there does not seem like there is a question here.

Comment: Pivot the data and then show that in the gridview.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson right, but some sample data, table structures etc would be helpful to answer the question.  At this point it would consist of guesswork.

Comment: @bluefeet Well if he wants help writing the pivot query definitely, but what he asked for was pivot the datatable, which while doable, would hardly be optimal.

Comment: Thank's for replies. I have two problems: I would to rappresent a data in pivot.The way are that or I pivot the DataGridView or I pivot mysql query. What is the method better than other? I appreciate yours replies.Thank's in advance

Comment: @GianniGiordano can you post some sample data, table structure and the expected result?

Comment: @bluefeet OK.If I query on Database, for example, SELECT mtScrap FROM production WHERE data = 'myData', of course I have mtScrap in those day or, if  alter query, SELECT SUM(mtScrap) ...WHERE data BETWEEN...I have the sum of mtScrap in a range of date.I would to have, day by day, the mtScrap value in DataGridView, where in up side of this control there are the day of month.It's possible to make this?Thank's in advance...